# pstree using VT100 graphic chars

Tags: osx, less, pstree

I am running `pstree` on MacOS Majave and wan to Show branches of processes using VT100 graphic chars:

```
$ pstree -g 2 | head -n 3
─┬◆ 00001 root /sbin/launchd
 ├──◆ 00049 root /usr/sbin/syslogd
 ├──◆ 00050 root /usr/libexec/UserEventAgent (System)
```

Tried to show it from less

```
ESC(BESC)0^Nqw`^O 00001 root /sbin/launchd
^N tqq`^O 00049 root /usr/sbin/syslogd
^N tqq`^O 00050 root /usr/libexec/UserEventAgent (System)
(END)
```

How could I solve such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

This gives me something very similar to the vt100 line drawing set:

```
$ pstree -g 2 -U|less
```